# Getting ducks in example images

Tags: graphics, fun, examples, tikzducks

> **This question led to a new package:**
>   [`duckuments`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/duckuments)

There are lots of cool example pictures in LaTeX. As far as I'm aware there aren't any good example duck images ;-(

Having ducks in the example images is, of course, essential for increasing the duckness of MWEs all over Tex.SE!

Thus I'd like to know: how do I get the duck to be in the center of an example image?

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikzducks}
\usepackage{graphicx}


\begin{document}
\includegraphics{example-image-a}
\tikz\randuck;
\end{document}
```

might produce:

[image]

There is, however, a problem with putting the duck next to the picture: it looks like a more permanent duck, not there for an example but there for all time. While every good duckument does feature a duck or a dozen, making the reader able to distinguish permanent and example ducks seems essential!

However, currently

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikzducks}
\usepackage{graphicx}


\begin{document}
\includegraphics{example-image-duck} %or with randuck
\tikz\randuck;
\end{document}
```

produces, with an error message (saying there is no file for the wanted example image):

[image]

Here there is no gray border telling the reader not to expect the duck in the final version of the duckument.

Is there any way I can get the two commands:

```
\includegraphics{example-image-duck}
\includegraphics{example-image-randuck}
```

To make an image like the one in the first example, but with a duck in the place of the a?

## Edit

It would be really cool, but it's probably not going to happen, to have the full `tikzducks` capabilities:

```
\includegraphics{example-image-duck[options]}
```

would thus act like options.

Also Torbjørn T. Posted the command:

```
\newcommand\ExampleDuck{ \begin{tikzpicture} \node [inner sep=0] {\includegraphics{example-image}}; \begin{scope}[shift={(-1,-1)}] \randuck \end{scope} \end{tikzpicture}}
```

that just needs an empty example image to be perfect. Now the only big hurdle is feeding includegraphics the result of the command `\ExampleDuck` if `example-image-randuck` is being loaded.

Comment: this calls for our resident duck expert @PauloCereda ;)

Comment: Yes. I sure hopes he saves the day ;-) Thanks for tagging him @naphaneal

Comment: Seems to be difficult, as `\includegraphics` expects ready-made pdf/png/ps files (like those in the `mwe` package).

Comment: `\newcommand\ExampleDuck{ \begin{tikzpicture} \node [inner sep=0] {\includegraphics{example-image}}; \begin{scope}[shift={(-1,-1)}] \randuck \end{scope} \end{tikzpicture}}`? @naphanel: you can only ping other commenters, or users who have edited the post, Paolo wont have been notified of that.

Comment: ignoring the random one, you can make \includegraphics{example-image-duck} work simply by uploading `example-image-duck.{eps,png}` to ctan.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. So we need a hook into the includegraphics and check if there is a duck, then run this command for the picture?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle great idea ;-)

Comment: maybe add a feature request at https://bitbucket.org/martin_scharrer/mwe ?

Comment: @samcarter I just did. Just needed to figure out how bitbucket works for creating issues ;-) thanks for pointing me there

Comment: @sam For `randomduck` It should rather be a `graphicx` feature request.

Comment: @AlexG graphicx is a duck free zone:-)

Comment: @david Watch out for `xpatch`!

Comment: @samcarter Could you add the capabilities created by ulrike to the tikzducks package?

Comment: I've clubbed together a small package to create "minimal working duckuments", similar to `blindtext`. It isn't on CTAN yet, but available on [github](https://github.com/Skillmon/ltx_duckuments). There is no documentation as of now.

Comment: Why break the established pattern? Why not `example-image-d`? Admittedly, `example-image-c` would need modification if cats or cauldrons or Christmas trees were ever required, though.

Comment: @cfr there already exist multiletter examples. (example-image-golden is not called example-image-g)

Comment: @ThorbjørnE.K.Christensen Hmm... do you think that would change if somebody supplied elephants and frogs, in addition to ducks?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Write a document example-duck:

```
\documentclass[tikz,multi]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikzducks}
\begin{document}
\foreach\x in {1,2,...,100}
{\tikz\randuck;}
\end{document}
```

and compile it.

Then you can use it like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xfp,graphicx}
\newcommand\getduck{\fpeval{randint(1,100)}}

\begin{document}

\includegraphics[page=\getduck]{example-duck}

\includegraphics[page=\getduck]{example-duck}

\includegraphics[page=\getduck]{example-duck}

\end{document}
```

[image] or [image]

### Edit

as requested in the comments here a more refined example-duck (the pointy head of the witch needs a rather large background):

```
\documentclass[tikz,multi]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikzducks}
\begin{document}
\foreach\x in {1,2,...,100}
{\begin{tikzpicture}
 \draw[fill=gray!50!white](-0.8,-0.8)rectangle(3,3);
 \draw[gray] (-0.8,-0.8)--(3,3)
             (3,-0.8)--(-0.8,3)
             (-0.8,1.1)--++(3.8,0)
             (1.1,-0.8)--++(0,3.8)
             ;
 \randuck;
 \node [anchor=center,rounded corners,draw=darkgray,opacity=0.5,fill=lightgray,rotate=30,font=\sffamily] at (1.1,1.1) {example duck};
 \end{tikzpicture}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: But these ducks look like nice permanent ducks. How will my editor know that they will not be in my final duckument? I sure do need my gray boxes ;-)

Comment: Really nice answer.  I do realize that I could join it with the comment by @TorbjørnT. To get the gray box ;-)

Comment: Hm. Do you want also a watermark "example-duck" over the duck?

Comment: I had not thought of that. but that would be equally nice to having the example background.

Comment: @ThorbjørnE.K.Christensen Better?

Comment: *Perfect* -- was to short to be a comment. But it really is enough to describe it.

Comment: Is there any way I could generate the duck duckument from the main duckument?

Comment: With -shell-escape you could do it. But imho it is more sensible to do it once and move it somewhere in the search path. Or ask @samcarter to add it to tikzducks.

Comment: You're proberbly right ;-)

Comment: actually all of the functionality you have created here would be nice to have in the tikzduck pagkage (also the `getduck` function, just so I don't have to define it in every duckument)

Comment: @ThorbjørnE.K.Christensen Maybe it would be better to have `getduck` etc in a separate package. I don't think it is worth loading the tikzducks package in every document where one wants to insert some dummy image. `tikz`, which is automatically loaded by the ducks is a very heavy package, which needs a lot of time to load and has a lot of potential to cause problems with other packages. Adding the the `example-duck.pdf` to the package sounds fine, I just don't have any experience if CTAN would like that?

Comment: fair enough. I neither have any idea how ctan works. (I've only used it for getting the documentation when I didn't have texdoc installed)

Comment: @samcarter the images from the mwe package are not a problem. But perhaps you should use a longer name, more along the line of the mwe names, e.g. example-image-duck. And you naturally could add other ducks from your showcase.

Answer (score 19):

The following could be used:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{tikzducks}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\newcommand\exampleDuck[1][]
  {%
    \adjustbox{#1}{%
      \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[black,fill=gray!50,thick] (0,0) rectangle (6,4);
        \draw[gray] (0,0) -- (6,4);
        \draw[gray] (0,4) -- (6,0);
        \draw[gray] (3,0) -- (3,4);
        \draw[gray] (0,2) -- (6,2);
        \node at (3,2) {\tikz\randuck;};
      \end{tikzpicture}
    }%
  }

\begin{document}
\exampleDuck[width=2cm]

\exampleDuck[height=5cm]

\exampleDuck
\end{document}
```

[image]

With [this package](https://ctan.org/pkg/duckuments) you can also use the following ([also on github](https://github.com/Skillmon/ltx_duckuments)):

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{duckuments}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\includegraphics[width=.5\textwidth]{example-image-duck}% takes a random page from the pdf
\includegraphics[width=.5\textwidth]{example-image-a}% still working

\blindduck% print one paragraph of text

\duckument% print a small duckument

\end{document}
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer (I feel that the other answer is more inline with my question, hence why it's accepted). I must give you the maddest of all the props for writing a package that gives filler duck text. I feel like one should write a package containing a duck roman, just to try rivaling the lipsum package ;-)

Comment: @ThorbjørnE.K.Christensen That's the idea of the package (in addition to patching `\includegraphics` to work with `example-image-duck`). But this morning between 1am and 2am I was just to tired to write something better than the above. Feel free to commit to the package :)

Comment: I might do that at some point ;-) It's a really cool idea to have a total duckification of all example parts of all duckuments. all hail the king duck ;-)

Comment: @ThorbjørnE.K.Christensen the package also contains `enumerate`, `itemize` and `description` duckifications (nested and unnested). Next on the to-do-list is turning it into a *.dtx, small duckumentation and uploading on CTAN.

Comment: And writing a hundred paragraphs more on the duck story, so all text needs can be fufilled by ducks and ducks alone ;-)

Comment: @ThorbjørnE.K.Christensen uploaded it to CTAN :)

Comment: The story of the blind duck is great -- so many nice details!

Comment: @samcarter thank you very much. You might contribute. If we really want to dethrone `lipsum` we have to write a whole duck epos.

Comment: I have teary eyes. I don't even know why exactly. Such are the emotions over the blind duck beginning of an epos!

Comment: [`duckuments`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/420279/1952) in action!

Comment: @Ignasi great to see it spread! I have just one problem with the early usage of it. It is not contained in TeXLive atm (but already in MikTeX). Therefore one needs to install it manually if he doesn't use the latest MikTeX -- just to reproduce something on TeX.SX. Still great!

Comment: Is there any possibility get first duck, second duck etc. like example-image-a

Comment: is it possible to have the duck images as portraits, too? it would make more sense to have them, e.g. for CVs or biographies.

Comment: @Khaaba you can use the `page` key of `graphicx`, e.g., `\includegraphics[page=1]{example-image-duck}`. And if you actually load `duckuments` together with `graphicx` (order doesn't matter), you'll get a random duck each time.

Comment: @naphaneal `example-image-duck-portrait` is included (since quite some time now, just forgot to notify you it seems).